# Переход от 32 разрядной системы к 64 разрядной

Tags: железо, ос

Возможно ли перестроить свою систему с 32 битной до 64 битной? и что для этого нужно сделать? нужно ли менять что то в системном блоке на более современное, или же это зависит от windows, у меня стоит vista 32 бит, была установлена по умолчанию при приобретении, смогу ли я на этот компьютер установить windows с 64 битами или же компьютер уже слишком стар для этого?

Comment: Как мы, все посетители SO, узнаем, насколько старый у вас компьютер? Экстрасенсы в отпуске.

Comment: все что вам нужно сделать - зайти в свойства системы и посмотреть, какой у вас процессор (можете сюда его написать). если проц 64,  ставьте что угодно

Comment: Если на вашей системе меньше 3,5Gb RAM, то переход на 64 бита не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае, замена 32 битного процессора на 64 битный потянет за собой замену метеринской платы, ОЗУ, и, возможно, блока питания. А там и видеокарта подтянется.

В целом, это приведет к практически полной замене содержимого системного блока.

Comment: однако на 32 разрядный процессор прекрасно встаёт  система х64

Comment: @LenovoID не в этой вселенной.

Comment: я не знаю в какой вы вселенной но на мой проц х32 встала и работает х64 и ОЗУ 2ггб и не поддаётся логике

Comment: @LenovoID, если вы поставили сборку от Васяна, она вам могла еще и не такое написать. Не сможет 32 битный процессор исполнять 64 битный код. Никак.

Comment: вы знаете я на mail.ru после того как установил на x32 систему x64 задал этот вопрос , там такая полемика была с матами в общем сисАдмины перегрызлись но факт у меня оставался фактом , врать мне смысла нету система стояла у меня два месяца и работала на ура , и не сборка была а обычная вин10 скачанная с оф сайта